# Is it possible to manage the global state of an application using only signals?

Tags: reactjs, signals, preact

I'm considering adopting Preact for library development.
I was thinking of using global state management libraries like recoil, jotai together for global state management, but I was wondering if signals alone would be enough for global state management.

I checked the official documentation of PREACT and it says that it can be used for global and local state management, but I wonder if it is really recommended for global state management of real(production) applications.

It seems to be relatively underused compared to other state management libraries, and I'm wondering if there's a reason for that. I've looked for related documentation or examples, but haven't found any, so I'd appreciate any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preact / signals maintainer here:

> it says that it can be used for global and local state management, but I wonder if it is really recommended for global state management of real(production) applications.

Yes, it absolutely can be.

You might see some value in tossing signals into the Context API, rather than directly importing them into components, but that's the only comment I'd really make. You absolutely can build production apps using them as both global and local state, many people already have.

> It seems to be relatively underused compared to other state management libraries

Well, Signals was only released last year September; most of the other tools you mention are quite a bit older. Newer tools of course see less use, though it's growing pretty aggressively if NPM download counts are anything to go by.

Comment: Do you have any examples somewhere about replacement for previous state? I have a react hook that returns previous state.

Comment: Returns the previous state? Not quite sure I follow -- can you provide an example showing what behavior you're after?

Comment: Check this, https://usehooks.com/useprevious